# Cannot start any docker container with "oci runtime error"

Tags: docker

I got the error below when i was trying to start a docker container.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 
invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: 
starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:334: 
running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"fork/exec /usr/bin/dockerd (deleted): no such file or directory\\\"\"\n".
```

I have tried different ways to run a container but non of them works, but the container which has been started is still running and still works, and here is my docker version info:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.24 (downgraded from 1.26)
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.6
 API version:  1.24 (minimum version )
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   78d1802
 Built:        Tue Jan 31 23:35:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Any suggestion or help would by appriciated!

Comment: If there is any other information that is needed please add a comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your docker client and server version is inconsistent. You need to retart your docker service. Try use this command then check the docker version, you will find the version is consistent and you can build docker image.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

```
sudo docker version
```