# OCI runtime create failed container_linux.go:370

Tags: docker

I searched this error and the solution given on threads is not working [Cannot start any docker container with "oci runtime error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096706/cannot-start-any-docker-container-with-oci-runtime-error)

So I am on MacOS and I have upgraded and restarted docker service multiple times.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache wget su-exec bash
RUN wget -qO- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-commandline/7.3.2/flyway-commandline-7.3.2-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvz && su-exec sh ln -s `pwd`/flyway-7.3.2/flyway /usr/local/bin
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/java /flyway-7.3.2/jre/bin
RUN mv /flyway-7.3.2/conf/flyway.conf /flyway-7.3.2/conf/flyway.conf.orig
COPY ./flyway.conf /flyway-7.3.2/conf/flyway.conf
CMD [ "/flyway-7.3.2/flyway migrate" ]
```

And here is my service in `docker-compose.yml`

```
  flyway:
    build: flyway
    container_name: flyway
    volumes:
      - ./flyway/migrations:/migrations
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
        db:
          condition: service_healthy
```

But when I say `docker-compose up` I get an error almost on all containers

```
Creating flyway ... error
ERROR: for flyway  Cannot start service flyway: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "/flyway-7.3.2/flyway migrate": stat /flyway-7.3.2/flyway migrate: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Comment: can you try `CMD [ "/flyway-7.3.2/flyway", "migrate" ]`? i assume `migrate` is a subcommand of the `flyway` program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OCI message is just part of how Alpine reports an error. But your actual error is in the CMD line.

Your syntax is not correct. Either you remove the `[]` or add as comma a @jakub pointed out.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd